# Use range instead of array of indivdual cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this code which works for cells A2-A4:

```
//The function onEdit ensures that checkboxes deleted  (by mistake) in the sheet are immediately re-created.
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(spreadsheet.getSheetName()=='MySheet') {   //to avoid executing for another sheet
    var checkboxCells = [
      'A2','A3','A4'];   
    var range = e.range;
    var value = range.getValue();
    var a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
    if (checkboxCells.indexOf(a1Notation) != -1 && value != 'TRUE' && value != 'FALSE') {
      range.insertCheckboxes();     
    }  
  }
};
```

However I need to work with a 1D range (since there are many cells) and hence I am trying to use this:

```
//The function onEdit ensures that checkboxes deleted  (by mistake) in the sheet are immediately re-created.
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(spreadsheet.getSheetName()=='MySheet') {   //to avoid executing for another sheet
    var checkboxCells =  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MySheet')
                                    .getRange('MyRange').getA1Notation();
    var range = e.range;
    var value = range.getValue();
    var a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
    if (checkboxCells.indexOf(a1Notation) != -1 && value != 'TRUE' && value != 'FALSE') {
      range.insertCheckboxes();     
    }  
  }
};
```

I think this second version should work, but it does not.
Why does it not work?

Comment: Try using a rangeList

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have a script that re-creates deleted checkboxes that are located in column A, correct?

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In order to check whether the edited cell is included in the specific range you expect, the following sample script can be used. (`var { range } = e;`)

  ```
    var checkboxCells = sheet.getRange('MyRange');
    var startRow = checkboxCells.getRow();
    var endRow = startRow + checkboxCells.getNumRows() - 1;
    var startCol = checkboxCells.getColumn();
    var endCol = startCol + checkboxCells.getNumColumns() - 1;
    var check = range.rowStart >= startRow && range.rowEnd <= endRow && range.columnStart >= startCol && range.columnEnd <= endCol;
  ```
- In order to check whether the edited cell is the checkbox, `isChecked()` can be used. In this case, when the cell is the checkbox, `true` or `false` are returned. When the cell is not the checkbox, `null` is returned. I thought that this might be able to be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your sheet name and your range.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var { range } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'MySheet') {
    var checkboxCells = sheet.getRange('MyRange');
    var startRow = checkboxCells.getRow();
    var endRow = startRow + checkboxCells.getNumRows() - 1;
    var startCol = checkboxCells.getColumn();
    var endCol = startCol + checkboxCells.getNumColumns() - 1;
    var check = range.rowStart >= startRow && range.rowEnd <= endRow && range.columnStart >= startCol && range.columnEnd <= endCol;
    if (check && range.isChecked() === null) {
      range.insertCheckboxes();
    }
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, when a cell is edited, when the edited cell is included in `MyRange`, it checks whether the edited cell is a checkbox when the edited cell is not a checkbox, the checkboxes are inserted into the edited cell.

#### Reference:

- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)

Comment: @mortpiedra Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.